# Is it legal to "simulate" Yubikey OTP autentication with an Arduino in own product?

Tags: arduino-leonardo

I found the following Github Repo that makes it possible to build your own Yubikey with an Arduino Leonardo device.

https://github.com/pagong/arduino-yksim

Pretty cool. However I am wondering if using this is legal at all?

YubiCo is a company and they sell sticks with the YubiKey OTP feature. The verification process happens through their servers. Somehow I can't quite imagine that the company YubiCo tolerates that their processes and products could be easily replaced by open source products? Maybe they have any patents or utility models? And I was not able to find any licensing information which makes sense since official firmware seems to be closed source. So I guess it makes sense that no licensing information is available since the yksim project is a reverse engineered thing?! But I'll admit quite frankly: I have no idea of all this.

I would also like to use this library and possibly also for my customer projects, but I need to know whether this is really allowed.

Hope someone can help me here and I know that the internet is no source for a 100% sure legal advice. But maybe someone has a clue or a hint for me.

Comment: This is the wrong forum, go to https://law.stackexchange.com/

Comment: https://opensource.stackexchange.com/ would be another place that might have good insight into this.

Answer (score 2):

According to https://www.yubico.com/blog/secure-hardware-vs-open-source/

> The YubiKey hardware with its integral firmware has never been open sourced, whereas almost all of the supporting applications are open source.

I am not a lawyer, however it would seem that providing you aren't copying their (non open source) hardware, but are merely replicating the functionality, then this would appear to be OK. **Disclaimer**: I may be wrong.

Having said that, I agree with the comment under the question, you should probably ask at https://law.stackexchange.com/

Questions about the legality of an Arduino application really are legal questions, not technical ones.